# process.call and cmd.exe

Tags: python, subprocess, cmd

I am trying to make a repeated call on the windows command line from my python code. For each fine in a directory, I need to run a command, and wait for it to finish.

```
try:
    directoryListing = os.listdir(inputDirectory)
    for infile in directoryListing:
        meshlabString = #string to pass to command line
        os.system(meshlabString)

except WindowsError as winErr:
    print("Directory error: " + str((winErr)))
```

I have been reading online, and it seems the preferred way to do this is with subprocess.call(), but I cannot figure out how to run cmd.exe through subprocess.call(). It kind of works right now using os.system(), but it gets caught up trying to run a bunch of processes at once, and dies. If someone could provide me a few lines of code on how to run a command on the windows command line, and if subprocess.wait() is the best way to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with subprocess, you have a few options.  The easiest is [call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
import shlex
return_code=subprocess.call(shlex.split(meshlabString))
```

shlex takes the string and splits it into a list the way the shell would split it.  in other words:

```
shlex.split("this 'is a string' with 5 parts") # ['this', 'is a string', 'with', '5', 'parts]
```

You could also do:

```
return_code=subprocess.call(meshlabString,shell=True)
```

but this way is a security risk if meshlabString is untrusted.  Ultimately, `subprocess.call` is just a wrapper on the `subprocess.Popen` class, provided for convenience, but it has the functionality that you want here.

Comment: Would I then call return_code.wait() to make it wait until the process was done? Also, Does .call just call cmd? and pass it whatever is in the parenthesis?

Comment: @Ronald Dregan: `.call()` executes either whatever is the first argument in the `args` passed to it is, or passes them to the shell when the keyword `shell=True` is given. On Unix, the default shell is `/bin/sh`. On Windows the default shell is specified by the COMSPEC environment variable which is usually set `cmd.exe`. It's all explained in the `subprocess.Popen()` constructors [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: @RonaldDregan Using `subprocess.call`, you don't need to `wait()` -- `subprocess.call` blocks until the process is finished.  The best way to invoke subprocess.call is like this:  (**form1**) `subprocess.call(['mycommand','--arg1','foo','--arg2','bar',...])` but (**form2**) `subprocess.call('mycommand --arg1 foo --arg2 bar',shell=True)` will work too.  In my above example, I use `shlex.split` to take something as a string and split it into a list which gets passed to `call` as in form 1.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for your help so far! 

OK, so I tried a few things, none of which worked. First, I tried 
`p = subprocess.call(meshlab,shell=True)`
that didn't do anything. Then I tried
`p = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe',meshlab])`
which just opened a blank prompt. Then I tried this:
`p = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe','echo "hi"'])`

with the same result. Any idea what's up? I would like the first one to work :)

Comment: @RonaldDregan -- I would expect the first one to work as well.  What is the string `meshlab`?  what happens if you paste that string into the command prompt?  What does the program do? does it need to recieve input from stdin?  what value does `p` have after the call (non-zero probably means an error occured in "meshlab")?  In your subsequent examples, I wouldn't expect the `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` to be necessary, but I don't work on Windows, so I can't be sure...

Comment: @mgilson meshlabstring is a location of a program C:\"Program Files"\meshlabserver that takes various arguments -i input -o output etc, all of which is contained in meshlabString. The command works fine when I just copy/paste it into the cmd prompt. I only added the cmd.exe path after things didn't work. Just trying new stuff.

Comment: @RonaldDregan -- I don't know how windows splits up filenames and such, but you might want to try quoting like this:  `meshlabString=shlex.split('"C:\Program Files\meshlabserver" -i input -o output')` (In other words, the whitespace in "Program Files" might be messing things up.)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).  The main difference is that by default `Popen` is non-blocking, whereas `call` is blocking.  This means that you can interact with `Popen` while its running, but you cannot with `call`.  You must wait for the process to complete with `call`, which you can modify `Popen` to run in the same manner by utilizing `wait()`.

`call` itself is just a wrapper around `Popen` as shown in the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e0df7db13d55/Lib/subprocess.py#l459):

```
def call(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete or
    timeout, then return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        try:
            return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
        except:
            p.kill()
            p.wait()
            raise
```

Using `call`:

```
import os
from subprocess import call
from shlex import split

try:
    directoryListing = os.listdir(inputDirectory)
    for infile in directoryListing:
        meshlabString = #string to pass to command line
        call(split(meshlabString)) # use split(str) to split string into args

except WindowsError as winErr:
    print("Directory error: " + str((winErr)))
```

Comment: What does the split do? I am running a command line .exe that takes arguments such as -i input -o output etc. Shouldn't I be able to pass this as one long string?

Comment: The split separates the string into passable arguments.  The effect will not hinder your intentions at all.